# Web application unable to connect to database

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

My server-side web application cannot login. After logging in, it goes back to the login page. It's a PHP web based app.

The database is in a separate folder `MysqlFile` contains adminlogin credentials.

`include/config.php` looks like that

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect(

/* Host Name */               "localhost",

/* Data Base User Name */     "admin@gmail.com",

/* Data Base Password */      "123",

/* Data Base Name  */         "myDbase"

);
if($con){ }  else { ?> <script>alert("Connection Error try again !!");</script> <?php } ?>
```

If the login is done successfully the index.php should redirect to dashboard /master.php. actually when I log in the URL shows the master.php and then comes back to the index.php to log in again without any error

thats index.php

```
<script>
    function alertmsg(){
        var username=$("#username").val();
        var password=$("#password").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "include/login.php",
            data: "username="+ username +"&password="+password,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){ $("#login").val('Connecting...');},
            success: function(data){
                if(data == "logindone")
                {
                    window.location="master.php";
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Invalid Username and Password !!! ";
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

include/login.php, cant really see where the problem at?

```
<?php
session_start(); include("config.php"); $uname=$_POST['Username'];$pass=$_POST['Password'];
if(isset($uname) && isset($pass))
{
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"select * from adminlogin WHERE Username='$uname' && Password='$pass' ");
    $res=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    if($res)
    {
        $_SESSION['uname']=$res['Username'];
        echo $con === true ? 'logindone' : 'nothing';
    }
    else
    {
        echo "loginfail";
    }
}  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in an Ajax function. With a failed connection to the database, the javascript alert would never be displayed as you are inside the Ajax call. You should follow the rules you've set in the Ajax call via the if statement.

```
echo $con === true ? 'logindone' : 'nothing';
```

With the above update, a successful connection to your database would execute the if statement in the Ajax call.

As a precaution,  add an `error: function()` to your Ajax call and handle it as you see fit.

Tip: please do not forget to use prepared statements..  `mysqli_bind_param()` etc

Comment: i have putted that statement in the login.php outside of the ajax statement. Do u mean that i have to put it inside the ajax function ?